# How to retrieve published post date from query in Gatsby with Contentful?

Tags: graphql, contentful, gatsby

With this kind of request, pulling post data from **Contentful** with **GraphQL** using `gatsby-source-contentful` plugin, looking for a way to access the post published date (post.sys.publishedAt) or updatedAt !

```
 {
  contentfulPost(id: { eq: 'postId' }) {
   --> publishedAt ?
   title
   image {
    responsiveResolution(width: 500, height: 500) {
      src
      srcSet
      height
      width
    }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

source-contentful plugin does not include the `sys` property in the GraphQL schema. it only includes the fields and the id.As a workaround, you can add a field that holds the date and it will be available for you in graphQL.

I hope this help

Edit ---------------

I just submitted a PR adding these options to gatsbyjs
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/2398
You can now access `updatedAt` and `createdAt` properties.

Comment: Thanx for your answer.

Comment: So is it mean that editor have to fill this field for having a post date or do you know a way to autocomplete this field with publishedAt data ?

Comment: I created an issue about adding `sys` fields to GraphQL https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2342

Comment: thanx ! it could be usefull for blog post !

Comment: I will try to find some time for it this week

Comment: The sys properties Are now included in the new version of the plugin